# Search bar input function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, input, searchbar

Sorry if I misspell something or use the wrong words, still very new at JS.
So I have created two different buttons in HTML that each goes to their separate functions with separate object lists. Under is a little example of how the object lists look like.
I'm trying to create a function, which allows the user to be able to search for words in an input search bar. But I'm having trouble creating this function to make it work for both buttons without having to click the buttons before adding a word in the search bar. So basically it should be able to get options from both lists if the search word matches.

Is this even possible or do I have to adjust the functions I already have to be able to make a function like this or? (Note the example does not contain an example of the search function, simply because I don't know where to even start)
Thank you so much for any help I get.

```
const liverpoolPlayers = [
    {
        name: "Mohamed Salah",
        age: 27,
        fromCountry: "Egypt",
        position: "Angrep",
        
    },

    {
        name: "Sadio Mane",
        age: 25,
        fromCountry: "Senegal",
        position: "Angrep"

    },

const playersContent = document.querySelector(".product-content")
const playersBtn = document.querySelector("#players-btn")

let showPlayers = () => {
    playersContent.innerHTML = ""
    liverpoolPlayers.forEach(player =>{
        playersContent.innerHTML += `
        <article class="product-article">
            <h3>Name:${player.name}</h3>
            <p>Age: ${player.age}</p>
            <p>Country: ${player.fromCountry}</p>
            <p>Postition: ${player.position}</p>
            <img ${player.img}>
        </article>
        `
    })
}
playersBtn.addEventListener("click", showPlayers)


const wineBtn = document.querySelector("#wine-btn")

let showWines = () => {
        playersContent.innerHTML = ""
        wineList.forEach (wine => {
        playersContent.innerHTML += `
        <article class="product-article">
            <h3>Name:${wine.name}</h3>
            <p>Age: ${wine.age}</p>
            <p>Country: ${wine.fromCountry}</p>
            <p>Postition: ${wine.position}</p>
        </article>
        `

    })

}

wineBtn.addEventListener("click", showWines)
```

HTML Search input

```
<section>
    <label>Filtrer etter søkeord</label>
    <input id="search-input">
    <button id="search-btn">Søk</button>
</section>
```

HTML buttons

```
        <primary-button id="players-btn" text="Country"></primary-button>
```

HTML buttons

Comment: where is HTML element with id `wine-btn`, and `players-btn`?

Comment: added the buttons to the question now

Comment: for some reason it wont add the wine button, but it is identical to the country button only the id i wine-btn and text = wine

Comment: Still I'm not able to reproduce the problem. It may be because, there is no `liverpoolPlayers` and `wineList` array.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: well there is not really any problems with the code above, im just wondering how i can create a function for a input search bar, that makes it possible for the user to write a word in the searchbar and then if the word matches any of the items in the object lists that specific box should come up.

Comment: You seem to know what to do? What have have you tried and where did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well-charged the batteries are in my mind-reading-unit, but since the telly is dodgy at the moment, I've given it a whirl.

Things to note:

- I've used the `template` element, since I find it makes code
  considerably cleaner and easier to read.
- I made up data, noting that your code only displays an image when the
  list being displayed is of the players. A rough work-around the
  difference between wines and players (the image field) is that I
  simply choose not to display images from the (potentially mixed-type)
  search results.
- You're doing essentially the same thing in the functions that display
  each of the lists. I've condensed these down into a single function
  that takes a pair of inputs - the array to show and a flag indicating
  whether or not there should be an attempt to display the image. A
  better way might be to discard this flag, and on a per-item basis,
  see if `elem.image == undefined`. If so, remove the `.image` element
  from the displayed article, otherwise, set its src attribute. This
  would alleviate (0) the need to send the true/false when displaying
  the player-list or the wine-list. It'd also 'just-work' when
  displaying mixed search results.

Give it a try:

```js
"use strict";

function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

const liverpoolPlayers = [{
    name: "Mohamed Salah",
    age: 27,
    fromCountry: "Egypt",
    position: "Angrep",
    image: 'player.png'
  },
  {
    name: "Sadio Mane",
    age: 25,
    fromCountry: "Senegal",
    position: "Angrep",
    image: 'player.png'
  },
];

const wineList = [{
    name: 'Riesling',
    age: 2,
    fromCountry: 'Germany',
    position: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Champagne',
    age: 27,
    fromCountry: 'France',
    position: ''
  },
]

window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);

function onLoad(evt) {
  byId('players-btn').addEventListener("click", onPlayersBtnClicked, false);
  byId('wine-btn').addEventListener("click", onWineBtnClicked, false);
  byId('searchBtn').addEventListener("click", onSearchBtnClicked, false);
}

function onPlayersBtnClicked(evt) {
  displayArray(liverpoolPlayers, true);
}

function onWineBtnClicked(evt) {
  displayArray(wineList, false);
}

function onSearchBtnClicked(evt) {
  let searchTerm = byId('searchInput').value;

  if (searchTerm === '') {
    byId('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'No results match an empty search-string!';
  } else {
    let resultsList = [];
    liverpoolPlayers.forEach(findMatch);
    wineList.forEach(findMatch);
    displayArray(resultsList, false);

    function findMatch(elem, index, arr) {
      if (elem.name == searchTerm)
        resultsList.push(arr[index]);

      else if (elem.age == searchTerm)
        resultsList.push(arr[index]);

      else if (elem.fromCountry == searchTerm)
        resultsList.push(arr[index]);

      else if (elem.position == searchTerm)
        resultsList.push(arr[index]);
    }
  }
}

function displayArray(arr, showImage) {
  let tgt = byId('outputDiv');
  tgt.innerHTML = '';
  arr.forEach(displayElement);

  function displayElement(elem, index, arr) {
    let newElem = byId('itemTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    newElem.querySelector('.name').textContent = elem.name;
    newElem.querySelector('.age').textContent = elem.age;
    newElem.querySelector('.country').textContent = elem.fromCountry;
    newElem.querySelector('.position').textContent = elem.position;
    if (showImage === true)
      newElem.querySelector('.image').src = elem.image;
    else
      newElem.querySelector('.image').remove(); // don't show the image

    tgt.appendChild(newElem);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <template id='itemTemplate'>
    <article class='product-article'>
      <h3>Name: <span class='name'></span></h3>
      <p>Age: <span class='age'></span></p>
      <p>Country: <span class='country'></span></p>
      <p>Position: <span class='position'></span></p>
      <img class='image'/>
  </template>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='players-btn'>Show All Players</button> | <button id='wine-btn'>Show All Wines</button><br>
  <input id='searchInput' placeholder='Name, Age, Country or Position' /><button id='searchBtn'>Search</button><br>
  <div id='outputDiv'></div>
</body>
```